# Pyspark: Intersection of multiple arrays

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following test data and must check the following statement with the help of pyspark (the data is actually very large: 700000 transactions, each transaction with 10+ products):

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

data = {'date': ['2014-01-01', '2014-01-02', '2014-01-03', '2014-01-04', '2014-01-05', '2014-01-06'],
     'customerid': [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3], 'productids': ['A;B', 'D;E', 'H;X', 'P;Q;G', 'S;T;U', 'C;G']}
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'])
```

"The transactions that exist for a customer ID within x days are characterized by at least one identical product in the shopping cart."

So far I have the following approach (example x = 2):

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master('local[*]') \
    .config("spark.driver.memory", "500g") \
    .appName('my-pandasToSparkDF-app') \
    .getOrCreate()
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true")
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("OFF")

df=spark.createDataFrame(data)

x = 2

win = Window().partitionBy('customerid').orderBy(F.col("date").cast("long")).rangeBetween(-(86400*x), Window.currentRow)
test = df.withColumn("productids", F.array_distinct(F.split("productids", "\;")))\
    .withColumn("flat_col", F.array_distinct(F.flatten((F.collect_list("productids").over(win))))).orderBy(F.col("date"))

test = test.toPandas()
```

[image]

So from every transaction we look 2 days into the past, group by customerid and the corresponding products are summarized in the "flat_col" column.

But what I actually need is the intersection of the shopping baskets with the same ID. Only then can I judge whether there are common products.

So instead of ['P', 'Q', 'G', 'C'] in the fifth row of "flat_col" there should be ['G ']. Similarly, [] should appear in all other rows of "flat_col".

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self join is the best trick ever

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import concat_ws, collect_list
spark.createDataFrame(data).registerTempTable("df")
sql("SELECT date, customerid, explode(split(productids, ';')) productid FROM df").registerTempTable("altered")
df = sql("SELECT al.date, al.customerid, al.productid productids, altr.productid flat_col FROM altered al left join altered altr on altr.customerid = al.customerid and al.productid = altr.productid and al.date != altr.date and datediff(al.date,altr.date) <=2 and datediff(al.date,altr.date) >=-2")
df.groupBy("date", "customerid").agg(concat_ws(",", collect_list("productids")).alias('productids'), concat_ws(",", collect_list("flat_col")).alias('flat_col')).show()
```

[image: spark output]

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. At the moment I am still having problems with  reproducing your results. I am trying something like this:

from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

SQLContext.sql("SELECT explode(split(productids, ';')) FROM df").registerTempTable("exploded")
....
I get the error message: sql() missing 1 required positional argument: 'sqlQuery'

Comment: That is because you launch it from notebook. You need to import sql context somehow. I run scripts in command line and it is done for me on the start when i do bin/pyspark. I corrected a bit the script, please rerun

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this  without **`self-join`** (*as joins are expensive **`shuffle`** operations in Big Data*) using `higher order functions` in **`spark 2.4`**. Functions used **`filter,transform,aggregate`**.

```
df=spark.createDataFrame(data)

x = 2

win = Window().partitionBy('customerid').orderBy(F.col("date").cast("long")).rangeBetween(-(86400*x), Window.currentRow)
test = df.withColumn("productids", F.array_distinct(F.split("productids", "\;")))\
    .withColumn("flat_col", F.flatten(F.collect_list("productids").over(win)))\
    .withColumn("occurances", F.expr("""filter(transform(productids, x->\
     IF(aggregate(flat_col, 0,(acc,t)->acc+IF(t=x,1,0))>1,x,null)),y->y!='null')"""))\
    .drop("flat_col").orderBy("date").show()

+-------------------+----------+----------+----------+
|               date|customerid|productids|occurances|
+-------------------+----------+----------+----------+
|2014-01-01 00:00:00|         1|    [A, B]|        []|
|2014-01-02 00:00:00|         2|    [D, E]|        []|
|2014-01-03 00:00:00|         2|    [H, X]|        []|
|2014-01-04 00:00:00|         3| [P, Q, G]|        []|
|2014-01-05 00:00:00|         4| [S, T, U]|        []|
|2014-01-06 00:00:00|         3|    [C, G]|       [G]|
+-------------------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Nothing is gonna shuffle if you make broadcast or partition by customerid, you confused several topics in one.

Comment: Broadcast can only take a maximum of 8GB and higher order function will always outperform a join operation even if you have it partitioned correctly . I’d suggest you spend some time learning about high order functions instead of calling me confused.

Comment: Also , to repartition by customer_id, the repartition in itself is an expensive shuffle operation.